# Python class property on abstract interface

Tags: python, interface, properties, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract interface that has an abstract property which is a class object that inherits from a second abstract interface.

I have 2 (abstract) interfaces; one for the `Car` and one for the `Passenger`. I also have the 2 corresponding concrete implementations.

I want the interface to enforce:

"*if you create a `Car` object, it **must** have a passenger property which **must** inherit from the `IPassenger` interface"*.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

####### Interfaces #######

class IPassenger(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def speak(self):
        """ passenger speaks """

class ICar(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def drive(self):
        """ car drives """
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def passenger(self):
        """ passenger object;
            how do I enforce that it must inherit from IPassenger? """

##### Implementations #####

class Passenger(IPassenger):
    def speak(self):
        print("Hi I am a passenger")

class Car(ICar):
    # -> OPTION 1 - this works but it is a class variable, not an instance:
    passenger = Passenger()

    def __init__(self):
        """ New car object made """
        # -> OPTION 2 - this is an instance variable but doesn't work
        self.passenger = Passenger()

    def drive(self):
        print("Car is driving")

def main():
    car = Car()
    
    car.drive()
    car.passenger.speak()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Option 1 works, but the `passenger` property on the `Car` class is a class variable, not an instance variable which is what I need.

Option 2 throws the error: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Car with abstract methods passenger`

How can I:

1. Enforce the `passenger` property to inherit from `IPassenger`?
2. Create a `Car` instance that has the `passenger` instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split between validation of the interface, which you can achieve with an abstract base class, and validation of the attribute type, which can be done by the setter method of a property.

Thus, no change in your ABCs

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class IPassenger(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def speak(self):
        ...

class ICar(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def drive(self):
        ...
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def passenger(self):
        ...
```

The passenger too is identical.

```
class Passenger(IPassenger):
    def speak(self):
        print("Hi I am a passenger")
```

Car is changed in two ways:

- it implements a passenger property to comply with the `ICar` interface
- a setter method is added to validate the type of input

```
class Car(ICar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.passenger = Passenger()
    
    @property
    def passenger(self):
        return self._passenger
    
    @passenger.setter
    def passenger(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, IPassenger):
            raise TypeError("passenger must be an IPassenger")
        self._passenger = value

    def drive(self):
        print("Car is driving")
```